# How to detect if user is accessing a uri under it's root route (/root_route -> /root_route/uri)

Tags: routes, laravel, laravel-4

I need to put restriction to users that are not logged-in in accessing the URIs under a route, like in this example, users can go to `/root_route/uri_1, /root_route/uri_2, /root_route/uri_3`.

Example:

```
/root_route/uri_1
/root_route/uri_2
/root_route/uri_3
```

I know how to put restriction on each of the URIs, but what I want is a little more dynamic, I want to put the code only once, and it checks if the URI the user is accessing is under this **/root_route**.

As much as possible I want the answer to be in **Laravel**

Route:

```
Route::get('root_route/uri_1',Controller@getUri1);
Route::get('root_route/uri_2',Controller@getUri2);
Route::get('root_route/uri_3',Controller@getUri3);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have a filter, don't you?

If so... There is very simple way to do that.

```
Route::when('root_route/*', 'yourFilterName');
```

Comment: I don't see any filters here but thanks anyway. I could edit your answer to include this but it doesn't feel right so I'll just post it here. Route::filter('yourFilterName',function(){//do codes here}) or Route::filter('yourFilterName','ControllerName@filterFunctionName') or Route::filter('yourFilterName','RootFilterClass')
ref: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters

Comment: I meant that "yourFilterName" is an existing filter:) I didnt want to write it - i don;t know what kind of authorisation you are doing.